# codeigniter views setup problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have two views from a form, one is loaded in my codeigniter index, and another is loaded in its on function.  how do i make the form work so that when i click submit on the first form it loads the new view/function as the new

Comment: Read Here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand your question,

i think you need to set the action of the first form to be the url of your second controller

```
<form action=/controller/form2 >
```

or you can do a redirect

or you can simply load the form2 instead of form1